# space of integrable simple functions is not complete

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Given $(\mathbb{R},S,\mu)$, where $S$ is the $\sigma$-field of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. On the vector space of integrable simple functions (two simple functions are equivalent if they differ on at most a null set), give the norm $\lVert f \rVert_1=\int |f(x)|d\mu (x)$. I want to construct a sequence of functions that is Cauchy for this norm but does not converge for the norm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint:** being Cauchy is equivalent to having a limit *in a perhaps bigger space*

Comment: I'm still trying to unerstand what this space is like and I don't know what that bigger space might be. I tried constructing a sequence of charactersitic functions whose norm goes to 0 but didn't seem to work. More specific hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a sequence converging to $x\mapsto x$ over $[0,1] $.